# Xamarin IOS: BLE

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect to my Bluetooth Low Energy Device. After finding the device and getting the peripheral object. I cannot connect to the Bluetooth Device from my iPhone and it does not call  **central.ConnectedPeripheral** method.

Another issue is that i cannot register the event ***central.ConnectedPeripheral += ConnectedPeripheral*** in the method.

*Error*: System.InvalidOperationException: Event registration is overwriting existing delegate. Either just use events or your own delegate:

```
class IOSBluetooth : IBluetooth
{
    private readonly CBCentralManager central;
    private CBPeripheral activePeripheral;
    SimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate myCentralDelegate;

    public bool IsScanning { get; private set; }

    List<CBPeripheral> connectedDevices = new List<CBPeripheral>();

    //List<CBPeripheral> discoveredDevices = new List<CBPeripheral>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current Bluetooth instance
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The Bluetooth Adapter instance</value>


    public IOSBluetooth(SimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate myCenDel)
    {
        myCentralDelegate = myCenDel;
        central = new CBCentralManager(myCentralDelegate, DispatchQueue.CurrentQueue);
        InitializeEvents();

        //   central.DiscoveredPeripheral += DiscoveredPeripheral; // Called when peripheral is discovered (Working)
        //   central.UpdatedState += UpdatedState; // Method Implemented - Tells us about the bluetooth powered state (On or Off). (Working)
        //   central.ConnectedPeripheral += ConnectedPeripheral; // Devices that are connected to Iphone -> Services and Characteristics discovery start from here
        //   central.DisconnectedPeripheral += DisconnectedPeripheral; // Disconnect the device from the iphone
        //   central.FailedToConnectPeripheral += FailedToConnectPeripheral;  // Failed to connect to Bluetooth Device
    }

    void InitializeEvents()
    {
        try
        {
           // central.ConnectedPeripheral += ConnectedPeripheral;
            central.FailedToConnectPeripheral += FailedToConnectPeripheral;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Intialization Failes");
            Console.WriteLine("Bluetooth.Connect " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void FailedToConnectPeripheral(object sender, CBPeripheralErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to Connect to Peripheral");
    }

    private void DisconnectedPeripheral(object sender, CBPeripheralErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // when a peripheral disconnects, remove it from our running list.
        if (connectedDevices.Contains(e.Peripheral))
        {
            connectedDevices.Remove(e.Peripheral);

        }
    }

    public void ConnectToPeripheral(CBPeripheral peripheral)
    {
        central.ConnectPeripheral(peripheral, new PeripheralConnectionOptions { NotifyOnConnection = true, NotifyOnDisconnection = true, NotifyOnNotification = true  });
    }

    private void UpdatedState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    //public override void DiscoveredPeripheral(object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("DiscoveredPeripheral: {0}", e.Peripheral.Name);
    //    discoveredDevices.Add(e.Peripheral);

    //}




    public void ConnectedPeripheral(object sender, CBPeripheralEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!connectedDevices.Contains(e.Peripheral))
        {
            connectedDevices.Add(e.Peripheral);

        }

        activePeripheral = e.Peripheral;
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to " + activePeripheral.Name);


        if (activePeripheral.Delegate == null)
        {
            activePeripheral.Delegate = new SimplePeripheralDelegate();
            //Begins asynchronous discovery of services
            activePeripheral.DiscoverServices();
        }

    }




    public async void BeginScanningForDevices()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BluetoothLEManager: Starting a scan for devices.");

        // start scanning
        IsScanning = true;
        central.ScanForPeripherals((CBUUID[])null); // Discover all the devices and Initiates async calls of DiscoveredPeripheral

        // in 10 seconds, stop the scan
        await Task.Delay(10000);

        // if we're still scanning
        if (IsScanning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("BluetoothLEManager: Scan timeout has elapsed.");
            StopScanningForDevices();


        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the Central Bluetooth Manager from scanning for more devices. Automatically
    /// called after 10 seconds to prevent battery drain. 
    /// </summary>
    public void StopScanningForDevices()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BluetoothLEManager: Stopping the scan for devices.");
        IsScanning = false;
        central.StopScan();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ListDevices()
    {
        return myCentralDelegate.DiscoveredDevices.Keys;

    }

    public bool Connect(string DeviceName)
    {
        StopScanningForDevices();

        if (!myCentralDelegate.DiscoveredDevices.ContainsKey(DeviceName))
            return false;

        var device = myCentralDelegate.DiscoveredDevices[DeviceName];

        // central.ConnectPeripheral(device, new PeripheralConnectionOptions { NotifyOnConnection = true, NotifyOnDisconnection = true, NotifyOnNotification = true });
        central.ConnectPeripheral(device);
        return true;
    }

    public void StartScanning()
    {
        if(central.State == (CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn)) 
            BeginScanningForDevices();
    }

    public void StopScanning()
    {
        StopScanningForDevices();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Another issue..." what error are you getting ?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Event registration is overwriting existing delegate. Either just use events or your own delegate:  (I improvised the Question)

Comment: Googling that error suggests the control isn't fully 'Xamarin compatible' and you should be using iOS events on this control rather than delegates (just as the error suggests).

Comment: Any pointers that what i have to do next to fix it. Any suggestion from code etc. I found a lot of examples on the internet that do the same way and i think that it works for them.

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39470/installed-5-9-build-431-event-registration-is-overwriting-existing-delegate-error

Comment: Well, i couldn't understand the problem from the given thread. Still figuring out the way to fix it

Comment: Have you tried calling the constructor without passing in your own delegate?

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the "Error: System.InvalidOperationException: Event registration is overwriting existing delegate. Either just use events or your own delegate" error, implement the `ConnectedPeripheral` method in the `SimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate` class. That class is being used as the iOS delegate (not to be confused with a C# `delegate`)  so all of the events from `CBCentralManager central` are being handled in the relevant methods in the `SimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate` class.

The idea here is that you can either use the iOS style delegate/protocol pattern, where a delegate class that implements an Obj-C/iOS protocol is assigned as the iOS/Obj-C delegate for the class that will call those protocol methods, or you can use C# style event subscriptions, but you can't use both on the same object.

More info on this is discussed on this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/delegates-protocols-and-events
It's a long read but well worth it if you are developing using Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Thank You. Following your advice to implement **ConnectedPeripheral** method in the **SimpleCBCentralManagerDelegate** class solve my problem.

Comment: Hi Sameed, did your FailedToConnectPeripheral event work? I cannot get mine to trigger. In fact all the events never trigger apart from UpdatedState. Any advice?